# dividing values between 2 rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in python and would like to ask anyone of a solution related to dividing 2 rows in a data set that contains 25000 rows. It is easier to understand it by looking at my screenshot.

Thanks for a help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your dataframe has a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html). Let's take the first four rows as an example. It could be problematic to let one of the row index levels have the same name (`loan_default`) as the column, so I'd change the column name to `count`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({(1954, 0): [9],
                   (1954, 1): [1],
                   (1955, 0): [91],
                   (1955, 1): [15]}).T
df.columns = ['count']
print(df)
```

```
        count
1954 0      9
     1      1
1955 0     91
     1     15
```

You can select all rows where a certain level of the MultiIndex has a certain value with [`df.xs()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html). This will give you two sub-series that you can divide by each other, which will be done element-wise:

```py
defaulted = df.xs(1, level=1) 
not_defaulted = df.xs(0, level=1)

odds = defaulted / not_defaulted
odds.columns = ['defaulting_odds']
print(odds)
```

```
      defaulting_odds
1954         0.111111
1955         0.164835
```

Note that this produces the odds of a loan defaulting for each year. If you would rather have the probabilities, you have to change the denominator. To get the percentage, just multiply by 100:

```py
prob = defaulted / (defaulted + not_defaulted)
prob.columns = ['defaulting_probability']
prob['defaulting_percent'] = prob.defaulting_probability * 100

print(prob)
```

```
      defaulting_probability  defaulting_percent
1954                0.100000           10.000000
1955                0.141509           14.150943
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try dividing with `shift` and groups.

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['year_of_birth'] = ['1954','1954','1955','1955', '1956', '1956']
df['loan_default'] = ['9','1','91','15','194','32']
```

Calculate the ratio:

```
df['percentage'] = df['loan_default'].div(df.groupby('year_of_birth')['loan_default'].shift(1))
```

Drop the NaNs:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['percentage'])
```

Convert ratio into a percentage:

```
df['percentage'] = df['percentage']*100
```